# Allow access to php file only from inside server

Tags: php, iframe

I'm embedding some php files output into another file by iframe

```
<iframe src="<url to php script folder>/index.php?some variables..." frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

What i want to do is to give access only to server (iframe, .. etc) not to visitors who wants to directly access by url.

Is that possible with PHP? What I must write inside index.php to prevent access of visitors? (not htaccess)

Comment: There are unreliable workarounds (referer) or cumbersome workarounds (nonce). Otherwise, no. And a downvote, btw, means "does not show any research effort".

Answer (score 3):

An iframe is accessed by you visitors and not the server so there is no difference for the server if the script was called from within and iframe or not, so no there is no way of doing what you want i a non-hackish, well working manner.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible with PHP.
And it does not much sense though.